# Данные в виде типизированного массива не импортируются в таблицу

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Я использую TypeScript. У меня есть такой интерфейс:

```
export interface tableItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  author: string;
  employee?: string;
  tracker: string;
  status: string;
}
...
let result: tableItem[] = [];
let entry: tableItem = {
  id: id,
  name: name,
  description: description,
  author: author,
  tracker: tracker,
  status: status
}
result.push(entry);
```

Я заполняю массив, состоящий из объектов, которые реализуют этот интерфейс.
Технически, получаю массив объектов. Далее я пытаюсь импортировать данные в компонент dx-react-grid из npm.
Если я заполняю данные из такой структуры, то таблица рендерится.

```
const data = [
  {
    author: "Система",
    description: "<p><s>gfdgdfsgbhdfsbnfdsnbsfn</s></p>",
    employee: "Вазген",
    id: "2538",
    name: "222",
    status: "Подана",
    tracker: "Ошибка",
  },
  {
    author: "Система",
    description: "<p><s>gfdgdfsgbhdfsbnfdsnbsfn</s></p>",
    employee: "Вазген",
    id: "2537",
    name: "222",
    status: "Подана",
    tracker: "Ошибка",
  }
];
```

Если же в качестве источника указываю массив из элементов, реализующих интерфейс tableItem, то данные не импортируются. В консоли данные выглядят одинаково, однако не понимаю, почему не происходит импорт данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо за помощь!

UPDATE:
Метод render():

```
console.log(data); // Выводим данные, объявленные явно
console.log(this.tableData); // Выводим данные, созданные массивом
return (
  <Grid rows={this.tableData} columns={columns} > // this.tabledata это массив. Если же я вместо него укажу именно структуру, указанную выше, то всё работает
    <FilteringState defaultFilters={[]} />
    <SelectionState
      selection={this.state.selectedRows}
      onSelectionChange={this.setSelection}
    />
    <PagingState
      defaultCurrentPage={0}
      pageSize={10}
    />
    <IntegratedPaging />
    <IntegratedFiltering />
    <IntegratedSelection />
    <Table />
    <TableHeaderRow />
    <TableSelection
      selectByRowClick
      highlightRow
      showSelectionColumn={false}
    />
    <TableFilterRow />
    <PagingPanel />
  </Grid>
);
```

Comment: не совсем понятно. Покажите пожалуйста код работающего и неработающего компонента.

Comment: @sneas Добавил код.

Comment: как вы получаете `this.tableData`?

Comment: @sneas В самой верхней части кода. Я заполняю массив result, а далее this.tableData присваивается значение массива result.

Comment: Добавьте `console.log(this.tableData)` прямо перед `return` в методе `render`, для того чтоб убедиться что там что-то есть.

Comment: @sneas Уже сделал, скриншот есть выше.

Comment: вы именно в методе `render` это проверяете? Спрашиваю, потому что подозреваю что на момент рендера `this.tableData` еще пуст.

Comment: @sneas Да, конечно. Вот часть кода:                                                                  console.log(data);
console.log(this.tableData);
 return (
   <Grid rows={this.tableData} columns={columns} >

Comment: братюнь, тогда не знаю. Код выглядет нормально. Подождём, может кто-то поумнее тут появится.

Comment: @sneas Спасибо за помощь, ты оказался прав, просто мы немного не учли, что логирование происходит позже. То есть на момент запуска рендера массив был пуст, т.к. он заполняется в асинхронном методе. А так как мы логировали данные внутри массива, они отобразились чуть позже якобы уже заполненными. Перекину его в стейт.

Comment: Да, как показывает опыт, то что будет рендериться (или как-то влиять на процесс ренедра) лучше всегда хранить в стейте.

Answer (score 0):

На момент запуска рендера массив был пуст, т.к. само его значение заполнялось в асинхронном методе. А так как мы логировали сами данные внутри массива, они отобразились чуть позже якобы уже заполненными.
Решением задачи является перемещение свойства tableData в State.